# Cannot osacompile from terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

On Mac OS X I am trying to do osacompile to create a `.app` file on my desktop. I do so from terminal it keeps throwing errors. If i just type osacompile i get stuck in like blank space - I can type whatever and nothing ever happens.

Image demonstrating the issues and errors being thrown when I try to run in terminal:
[image]

Please help to successfully run out of terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the space in your app name with a backslash.

```
osacompile -x -o /Users/sebas/Desktop/My\ Application\ test.app utils/launcher.scpt

osacompile -x -o /Users/noi/Desktop/my\ cut.app ...
```

This works in Mac OS X 10.10.1 Terminal